# rails 4.0.3 rspec 3.0.2 undefined method 'sign_in' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

this test fails

```
describe "forbidden attributes", type: :request do

     # let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      let(:params) do

        { user: { zero_cost: true, password: user.password, password_confirmation: user.password } }

      end

      before do

        sign_in user, no_capybara: true

        patch user_path(user), params

      end

      specify { expect(user.reload).not_to be_zero_cost }

    end
```

a link to my github is [here](https://github.com/ramblingbarney/freezing-octo-batman) for the full code

It was previously run for the admin boolean table column but I switched it to another column to see if the test would still fail, same error.

the user controller is

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]

  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def index

    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])

  end

  def show

    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end

  def new

    @user = User.new

  end

  def create

    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save

      sign_in @user

      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample!"

      redirect_to @user

    else

      render 'new'

    end

  end

  def edit
  end

  def update

    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)

      flash[:success] ="Profile updated"

      redirect_to @user

    else

      render 'edit'

    end

  end

  def destroy

    User.find(params[:id]).destroy

    flash[:success] = "User deleted."

    redirect_to users_url

  end

  private

  def user_params

      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)

  end

  # before filters

  def signed_in_user

    unless signed_in?

      store_location

      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."

    end

  end

  def correct_user

    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)

  end

  def admin_user

    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?

  end

end
```

Comment: Better if you generate the test with controller: rails g controller Users index show new create update destroy

Answer (score 1):

Remove sign_in from your test:

```
describe "forbidden attributes" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before do
    patch :update, id: user.id, user: { zero_cost: true, password: user.password, password_confirmation: user.password }
  end

  specify {
    expect(assigns(:user).zero_cost).to be_true
    expect(response).to redirect_to(user_path(assigns(:user).id))
  }
end
```

Comment: User pages index forbidden attributes non edit 
     Failure/Error: patch :update, id: user.id, user: { zero_cost: true, password: user.password, password_confirmation: user.password }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `patch' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPages::Index::ForbiddenAttributesNonEdit:0x0000000583af90>
     # ./spec/features/user_pages_spec.rb:111:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
above produces this error

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the method 'Sign in' in 'spec / support / utilities.rb' that way you can access it in your tests.

You can confirm this checking the file 'utilities.rb' in Michael Hartl sample App in GitHub:

https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_4_0_upgrade/blob/master/spec/support/utilities.rb

Comment: yes, a good answer but in this case the helper method has been created

Answer (score 0):

the rails tutorial originally puts this test in the describe edit section but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305598/possible-bug-in-rails-4-tutorial-section-9-6-exercise-1) (solution 18305598 ) it advised to put it with 'user' tests

removing the sign_in user within the before block is correct

this is the corrected working test

```
   describe "forbidden attributes", type: :request do

      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      let(:params) do

        { user: { admin: true, password: user.password, password_confirmation: user.password } }

      end

      before do

        patch user_path(user), params

      end

      specify { expect(user.reload).not_to be_admin }

    end
```

this block of code at the top of the script must be run

```
before(:each) do
  sign_in user
  visit users_path
end
```

means I cannot run just the single test with this command

```
bundle exec rspec spec/features/user_pages_spec.rb -e "forbidden attributes"
```

because the it requires the user to be signed in